# How to set a formula for such a subsequence?

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

There are two sequences $\{a_n\}$ and $\{b_m\}$.
The sequence $\{c_k\}$ is defined as follows: the first 5 terms
of $\{c_k\}$ are the first 5 terms from $\{a_n\}$ , the following 6 terms of $\{c_k\}$ are first 6 terms from $\{b_m\}$ ,
the following 5 terms of $\{c_k\}$ are the following 5 terms from $\{a_n\}$ (starting with $a_{6}$ ), then 6 following
terms of $\{c_k\}$ are the following 6 terms from $\{b_m\}$ (since $b_{7}$ ), and so on, the process continues
periodically, at each step we take another 5 terms from $\{a_n\}$ and another 6 terms from $\{b_m\}$. The problem is that I want to set $\{a_n\}$ and $\{b_m\}$ as subsequences of $\{c_k\}$ but I have no idea how to do it. Is it possible in general?

Comment: I think so. You have described what is going on clearly. All the $a$'s are present in the sequence $c$.

Comment: It is just a matter of throwing out all the $c$'s that came from sequence $b$. It will start as $a=(c_1,c_2, \dots)$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, that is totally possible. You are assigning values in groups of 11, where you first assign five values of $(a_n)$ and then six values from $(b_n)$. So if
$$ k = 11l + r$$
with $0\leq r < 11$ then for $r<5$ we have
$$ c_k = a_{5l+r} $$
and for the rest we have
$$ c_k = b_{6l+(r-5)} $$
Then for any $n\in\mathbb N$ we have $n=5l+r$ for some $0\leq r <5$ and some $l$. Then we get:
$$ a_n = c_{11l+r}$$
Similarly if $n=6l+r$ with $0\leq r<6$ we have
$$ b_n = c_{11l+r+5} $$
Thus you get $a_n$ and $b_n$ as subsequences of $c_k$.